# Android background image for multiple screens

Tags: android

I read a topic about [multiple screen support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), but I don't understand why I need a different picture for every screen size if I can stretch image by setting

```
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bk"
```

for every screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't *have* to have a different image for each screen size. You certainly can just use `fill_parent` and just use the same image. The only issue is that it usually won't look as good. In fact, in some cases it will look absolutely terrible. Assuming that you're fine with your image being stretched though, you *can* just use one image.

Answer (score 2):

If your background image is not a plain image, and has a lot of detail, then it renders better if it is the exact size needed.  Shrinking a large image to small may make it look grainier than you want.

However, you can still do it.  Make sure to make AVDs with different screen sizes, so you can see how it might look.